# What's the speed of a fully laden dragon?

Tags: hoard

Does collecting more loot slow down a dragon in Hoard?

If so does the speed skill or carry skill offset this?

Comment: African or European...?

Comment: @Albort you win an internet, my friend.

Comment: @Albort, saw an advert on SuperUser for this question, came to see if that had been posted as a comment, was not dissapointed.

Comment: I was literally entering this thread to post that.

Comment: @Albort I had the same thought as you... and so did a lot of people. Great comment! For people that don't get it: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H4_9kDO3q0w

Comment: @Holger: I think you mean this one... http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pWS8Mg-JWSg&feature=related

Comment: @Albort well actually the setup for the video you linked is in the video I linked, but yeah the "African or European?" is from the video you left. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, your dragon will keep the same speed.

The speed skill just makes your dragon fly faster overall

Comment: Exception: carrying a sorcerer tower gem will always make you fly slower.